# Symmetric Difference b/w unsorted arrays

Tags: java, c++, c, arrays, algorithm

I have tried to solve this question while preparing for my interview. The question is as follows:

> **Find the Symmetric Difference of Arrays**
>
> **Input:** two arrays of integers
>
> **Output:** one array of integers
>           which occur in only one (not both) arrays
>
> **Test case:**
>
> Input:
>
> ```
>            [ 1, 7, 8, 2, 4, 5 ]
>
>            [ 3, 5, 1, 7, 6, 9 ]
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
>            [ 8, 2, 4, 3, 6, 9 ]
> ```

The Methods I have come up with are

- Brute for of running two loops , finding common elements and then printing the rest - `T=O(n2)`
- Sort both the arrays and follow a similar strategy to Merge Procedure of MergeSort - `T=O(nlogn)`

I cannot think of any method in O(n) . Is there any lower time complexity algorithm to solve this?

You can also suggest some language specific library methods in c++ / java

Comment: Are there bounds on the value of the integers?

Comment: Can be used counting when there is to a limited extent.

Comment: If the values are reasonably lower and upper-bound you can use a lookup table. Its the only true O(n) algorithm that immediately springs to mind.

Comment: Is each value in each of the two arrays unique (e.g. could the first array be `[1, 1, 7, 8, 2, 4, 5]`)?

Comment: @Jashaszun The  question is copy pasted form a blog.But I too had this doubt and it causes  significant trouble for coding this.

Answer (score 7):

The quickest way is to put all the values of the first `Array` into a `HashTable` and then do a `contains()` to see if the values from the second `Array` exist. This will give you an expected time complexity of `O(n)`

Comment: *Average* time complexity of O(n). It's O(n^2) worst case.

Comment: How do you get the non duplicate values from the first array?

Comment: @T.C.Not true, the average and worst case for searching a `HashTable` is `O(n)`

Comment: @T.C.: Expected linear time if you use a decent hash table.  "Worst case" where you maximise over the randomness as well isn't a sensible metric in very many situations.

Comment: @Nanos if `contains()` returns true you can just remove that value from the `HashTable` leaving you with the difference from the first `Array`

Comment: @rsay3 No, it's not. Single inserts and searches on hash tables are average case O(1) and worst case O(n).

Comment: @T.C.You are right, average is `O(1)` but worst is still `O(n)` not `O(n^2)`

Comment: @rsay3 that makes, sense, but how would you handle if that value appeared in the second array again? sorry, just curious how your algorithm would work. or are we assuming there are no duplicates in the arrays?

Comment: @rsay3 `O(1)` average/`O(n)` worst case is for a single search. You are performing `n` searches, so worst case is `n * O(n) = O(n^2)`.

Comment: @Nanos Well if you are looking for the symmetric difference then if there are duplicates, say two 1's in the first array and none in the second, then both will be in the `HashTable` and the resulting `Array`. If there were two 1's in the first and one 1 in the second then `contains` will return true and remove both instances leaving the resulting `Array` with no 1's

Comment: @T.C.: Your worst-case analysis is still uselessly pessimistic no matter how many times you repeat it.  You want to analyse the *expected* running time instead.

Comment: @tmyklebu The only reason I repeated it is to correct the false claim that the worst case is `O(n)`. Regardless of the usefulness of the true information, false information is false information and should be corrected.

Comment: @T.C.: Under suitable assumptions, nothing in the answer is wrong.  The word "expected" before "time complexity" would clarify things---"expected", not "average-case" because the averaging is done over the entropy rather than over the input space---but it is correct as written.

Comment: @tmyklebu I agree that the answer as written isn't wrong as such. I was referring to the third comment.

Comment: @tmyklebu Could you define "entropy"? I sometimes hear it and never know what people mean by it; can't find definitions that I find applicable, either.

Comment: @G.Bach: Here I'm speaking about the numbers spat out by the random number generator---you want to assume that the random number generator is not trying to screw you.  (This use of "entropy" appears to be nonstandard.)  "Shannon entropy" is something different and the entropy of a physical system is something different again and Linux's "entropy pool" is something different yet again.

Comment: @T.C.: Yeah, okay.  That comment's pretty wildly wrong.

Comment: @tmyklebu Hm, that doesn't illuminate it for me at all. Also, I don't quite understand how you distinguish average-case and expected case; iirc, average-case is defined as the sum over the complexity required for all instances of a given size, divided by the number of instances. Expected case is similar, but instead of assuming a uniform distribution, it assumes some probability measure on the set of instances and weights each instance with its measure. For randomized algorithms, you'd also average over the random bit choices in both cases.

Comment: @G.Bach: Average case is the average over all possible inputs.  Expected worst-case is the worst over all possible inputs of the average over all possible random strings.